# How to Bind Years in DropdownList

Tags: javascript, html, leap-year

Here I have a task that Years Should be Bind in DropdownList Like 1947 to 2016 if I write Code Like

```
<select>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>

</select>
```

Its Taken whole day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done by javascript for example:

```
<select id="year"></select>
```

JScript:

```
var year = 1947;
var till = 2016;
var options = "";
for(var y=year; y<=till; y++){
  options += "<option>"+ y +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

Comment: Thank u sooo much Mr Claudio

Comment: @MdHohn, Glad could help. You may accept this as an answer.

Comment: y not Claud its my duty